# Can't install ubuntu 18.04 LTS BECAUSE THESE SERVICES RUNNING 100% OF MY CPU

Tags: system-installation

okay at first i've installed and  used ubuntu days ago but i had to uninstall it because of partition issue... i was just trying to switch from windows 10 to ubuntu so i uninstalled windows completely then i tried to install ubuntu 18.04 from live usb but after the boot my cpu has high usage by (systemd-journal ... rsyslogd ... kworker/1:2 -e and +e) ive been trying to disable or restart the services but it doesn't work  and thats why i cant install ubuntu cause it crashes  during installing ... also i've tried the (pci=nomsi) in grub but it gives me 2 errors ...first pci=nomsi is unknown and the second you need to load the kernel first ... please help me fix this. thanks

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Some require boot parameters like the pci=nomsi you tried. But if  error, did you add it to grub in correct place. It should replace quiet splash on linux line, like nomodeset, scroll down for grub with UEFI boot example:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it &  UEFI black grub menu
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the live usb and choose "Try Ubuntu without installing". When Ubuntu is up and running run gParted (type "gparted" in a terminal) and format an ext4 partition on your hard drive. Then reboot from the live usb and choose "Install Ubuntu" and install 18.04 onto the ext4 partition you have created.

Comment: thanks for your answer ... but that is not working for me because that wouldn't fix the cpu usage and thats why i can't install...plus i have no partition on my hard disk cause i couldn't install at all to make any partition... so 980 GB free :/